# unix oracle connectivity

Tags: database, sql

[image]Operating system : Windows8.1

```
i use Linux ubuntu using vmware 

Today i have installed oracle database 11g release 2 in particular drive 

i want to access database via linux/ubuntu  

i able to access via windows command prompt
```

using the query

```
set oracle_sid=datbase_name ;

Sqlplus; 
username ;
password ;

SQL> select sysdate from dual ; 


 SQL> cl scr ;

SQL>exit;
```

i need to know , is it possible to connect and access database via ubuntu/Linux/

once i type

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

i got the error sqlplus not found 
`i know i have to set the oracle environment ,` but i don't know how ?

Comment: Your first line says this is on Windows 8.1; that's just the host OS, right? As in, it's otherwise uninvolved?

Comment: yes Windows 8.1 , and i use ubuntu using Vmware

Answer (score 1):

At minimum, you need to set `ORACLE_HOME`. You probably also want to add something to `PATH`.

When you installed Oracle, you picked a home directory. For example, let's say you used `/opt/oracle/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1`. Then you'd run something like this in the shell to set the environment:

```bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
PATH="$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin"
```

Oracle comes with a `oraenv` script you can run as `. oraenv` (note the dot in front, it's important) if your database is registered in `/etc/oratab`.

If you want that second SQL*Plus line to work, you also need to set ORACLE_SID to your database's SID.

PS: There is a `rlwrap` program you can install (from universe) that, if you run it around SQL*Plus (e.g., `rlwrap sqlplus`) will make SQL*Plus line editing *much* nicer.

Comment: yes , i shared a snapshot , where you can see the path . i have installed in windows operating system

Comment: @vikas wait... I thought you installed Oracle under Ubuntu? If not, you need to install the Oracle client at least.

Comment: yes , i installed SQL*plus oracle client , i shared the snapshot

Comment: @vikas that's a screenshot of installing Oracle on Windows, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, after the OP gets the oracle environment on the Linux guest working, he will likely have to set up some networking such as TNS to let the Linux oracle client access the Windows oracle server.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yep, I think the Oracle Instant Client installer will prompt to set up tnsnames.ora. Oracle config files strike me as beyond the scope of this site.